# Can someone add a gradient to my boring UIButton?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I'm struggling with getting a gradient layer lined up with my button.  I'm hoping someone can help me out real quick so my button isn't so bjaaah.

Here's what I'm working with:

```
UIButton *tmpBtn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:theFrame];

[tmpBtn setTintColor:buttonColor];
[tmpBtn setBackgroundColor:buttonColor];
tmpBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
tmpBtn.layer.borderWidth = 1;
tmpBtn.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
```

(buttonColor is being passed into the method, its just a single color right now)

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Adding gradient to your button

```
 CAGradientLayer *gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
 gradientLayer.frame = yourButton.layer.bounds;
 gradientLayer.cornerRadius =yourButton.layer.cornerRadius;
 [yourButton.layer addSublayer:gradientLayer];
```

Comment: Why add an answer to a question that was already closed as a duplicate?

Comment: I added an answer before it marked bas duplicate

Comment: No, you added your answer 11 minutes after it was closed as a duplicate. Look at the timestamps.

Comment: Actually I was giving answer from my mobile phone Stackoverflow app. Once I added answer I edited my answer five times.May be the last edited answer time showed the time.While I was giving answer I did not see the question marked as duplicate.Realy I did not know